# Difference between <a> and <link>

Tags: html

I am a HTML beginner and I was wondering if there is a difference between these two tags, aren't both of them for url?

Is there a significant difference between those two tags. Also what is bootstrap and is it recommend to use it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: Did you read the documentation? They do completely different things.

Comment: So <a> is exclusive for hyperlinks and <link> is to establish relationships to the document. But what else could link be used for other than importing the css file?

Comment: `<link>` is basically used for referring `external file` specially `stylesheet` whereas. `<a>` is an anchor tag which defines hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

A link pulls in external data, usually a stylesheet. An anchor navigates the page, either internally within itself or to an outside page.

Bootstrap is a pre-built framework of commonly-used webpage elements. It's really great for rapid prototyping of a website. It allows a user to quickly generate a mobile responsive website with lots of nicely styled bells and whistles (buttons, menus, etc). I think it's a better suited tool for AFTER you've taught yourself HTML and CSS. I don't think you should jump in with Bootstrap to learn.

Comment: So link is a way to pull data in and an anchor is a method of navigation?

Comment: @Pablo yes, also anchors with ids can be used to navigate to specific location in page itself

Comment: What is better to use the name attribute, the class tribute, or the id attribute for that matter?

Comment: Definitely ID. By definition, no more than one element in the page can have a given ID. Thus, it's a perfect candidate for navigating within the page.